# Is this proof of Milnor's lemma valid? the one about Newtons method and super-attractive fixed-points corresponding to simple roots

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, dynamical-systems, newton-raphson, complex-dynamics

> **(Milnor's Lemma)** Every **simple root** of $f (t)$ is a
>     super-attractive fixed-point of $N_f (t)$ where 
>   $N_f (t) = t - \frac{f (t)}{\dot{f} (t)}$
>   since a superattractive
>     fixed-point is one such that its multiplier $\lambda_f(t) = \dot{f} (t)= 0$ so that its
>     multiplicity is
>     \begin{equation}
>     m_f (t) = \frac{1}{1 - \lambda_{N_f} (t)} = \frac{1}{1 - 0} = \frac{1}{1}
>     = 1
>   \end{equation}
>
> John Milnor. *Dynamics in One Complex Variable*. Annals of
>   Mathematics Studies 160. Princeton University Press, 2nd  edition,
>   2006. Problem 4-g p.54

**Proof.** 
Let $\alpha$ be a root $f (\alpha) = 0$ then the multiplier of its Newton map
is $$\lambda_{N_f} (\alpha) = \frac{f (\alpha) \ddot{f}
(\alpha)}{\dot{f} (\alpha)^2} = 0$$ since $f (\alpha) = 0$ the entire expression
$\frac{f (\alpha) \ddot{f} (\alpha)}{\dot{f} (\alpha)^2}$ is equal to 0 since
due to the ordering of operations the value of $\dot{f} (t)$ or $\ddot{f} (t)$
is never required to be known in order to know the value of $\lambda_{N_f}
(t)$ when $f (t) = 0$.

If any term in the product is $0$ then the entire
product takes the value $0$. The multiplicity is related to the multiplier by
$$m_f (t) = \frac{1}{1 - \lambda_{N_f} (t)} = 1$$ and therefore simple. Since
$$m_f (t) = \frac{1}{1 - \lambda_{N_f} (t)} \forall \lambda_{N_f} (t) \neq
1$$ then it is known that $\lambda_{N_f} (t) = 0$ when $f (t_{}) = 0$
therefore the point $\alpha$ is a superattractive fixed-point corresponding to
a simple zero at $\alpha$.

Since we now know that $m_f = (\alpha)$ and
therefore the fero at $f (\alpha) = 0$ is simple, we therefore know that the
denominator $\dot{f} (t)$ of the multiplier $\lambda_{N_f} (t)$ cannot
vanish so that $\dot{f} (\alpha) \neq 0$ since that would imply that
$\alpha$ is not a simple root, which would be a contradiction to the already
established fact that $m_f (\alpha) = 1$ when $f (\alpha) = 0$.

Comment: Why the change from $f$ to $Z$? Are you missing a square in the denomiantor of $λ_f(α)=\dfrac{f(α)f''(α)}{f'(α)^2}$? Is super-attractive equal to super-linear convergence? Is the sometimes winded formulation in the proof some attempt to formulate an analytic result in an algebraic context?

Comment: The change from f to Z isn't necessary.. but I happened to be applying it to a function called Z elsewhere. Thanks for pointing out the typo of the missing square in the denominator. I've corrected both the mistakes. I guess it could be that yes.. I was wondering if the reasoning is valid.. even if a bit wordy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m=m_f(α)$, then $f$ factorizes as $f(x)=(x-α)^mg(x)$ with $g(α)\ne 0$. Then
$$
N_f(x)=x-\frac{(x-α)^mg(x)}{m(x-α)^{m-1}g(x)+(x-α)^mg'(x)}\\
=α+(x-α)\left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)+O((x-α)^2)
$$
so that indeed the stated connection exists, at simple roots the linear coefficient is zero, Newton's method is quadratic. And conversely, if at a root of a sufficiently smooth function the linear coefficient in the expansion of the Newton operator vanishes, then the multiplicity is one, the root is simple.